# Ansibel Playbook: run a task only one time and passing variable into roles

Tags: ansible

I'm still relatively new to Ansible and stumbled across something today that really wonders me. Here's the scenario:

- I have a playbook with multiple roles
- The playbook runs across multiple hosts
- When starting the playbook I want to execute a single task once (that's all it takes and for resource reasons it should only be executed once).
- This task contains for example a shell-command (e.g. API-Command to a public service in the internet). This shell-command returns a value, which I want to store in a variable.
- I want to use the value of the variable in the roles & tasks of the playbook on all hosts.
- The task can be executed on localhost

Is there a way to make something like this in Ansible? How can such a playbook look like?

I have something like the following example in mind:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost

  pre_tasks:
  - name: get an token via api
    shell: curl --silent https://api.example.com/token | grep -s 'something'
    register: result
  - set_fact:
    token: "{{ result.stdout }}"

- hosts: all
  become: true

  roles:
    - role_using_token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is the run_once paramameter, cf :https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html. It will "apply any results and facts to all active hosts in the same batch" (unless you use the delegate_facts parameter)

you can combine it with the delegate_to parameter

```
---
 - hosts: all

  # pre_tasks:
 - name: get an token via api
    shell: curl --silent https://api.example.com/token | grep -s 'something'
    register: result
    run_once: true
    delegate_to: localhost

 - set_fact:
    token: "{{ result.stdout }}"
    
 - ...
```

Comment: This is really helpful an works perfect. THX!

Comment: Make sure this is what you want. The token is shared by active hosts in the same batch. The next batch will again ask for a token.

Answer (score 0):

Given four hosts in the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
host_4
```

Set `serial: 2` in the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: all
  serial: 2

  vars:

    cmd: 'date +"%H:%M:%S"'

  pre_tasks:

    - block:
        - shell: "{{ cmd }}"
          register: result
        - set_fact:
            token: "{{ result.stdout }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: token
    - pause:
        seconds: 3
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [shell] *********************************************************************************
changed: [host_1 -> localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1 -> localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  token: '16:16:41'
ok: [host_2] => 
  token: '16:16:41'

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
Pausing for 3 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [host_1]

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [shell] *********************************************************************************
changed: [host_3 -> localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [host_3 -> localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_3] => 
  token: '16:16:45'
ok: [host_4] => 
  token: '16:16:45'

  ...
```

You can see the second batch run the command again. A better option is to `delegate_facts: true` in *pre_tasks* and create the variable *hostvars.localhost.token* if not defined. Use this variable in the whole play and set *token* for other hosts in *tasks*. This way you don't repeat the command in each batch

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  serial: 2

  vars:

    cmd: 'date +"%H:%M:%S"'

  pre_tasks:

    - block:
        - shell: "{{ cmd }}"
          register: result
        - set_fact:
            token: "{{ result.stdout }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true
      when: hostvars.localhost.token is undefined

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        token: "{{ hostvars.localhost.token }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: token
    - pause:
        seconds: 3
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [shell] *********************************************************************************
changed: [host_1 -> localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1 -> localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [host_1]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => 
  token: '16:24:01'
ok: [host_2] => 
  token: '16:24:01'

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
Pausing for 3 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [host_1]

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [shell] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [host_3]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
skipping: [host_3]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [host_3]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_3] => 
  token: '16:24:01'
ok: [host_4] => 
  token: '16:24:01'
```